# Why do I keep getting the "The number of variables in newx must be 8" error when I'm trying to predict on the test set in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict, lasso-regression

I'm trying to build a logistic regression with a dataset containing 9 variables and 3000 observations. This is what it looks like with the head() function:

```
 Sex Length Diameter Height WholeWeight ShuckedWeight VisceraWeight ShellWeight Age
1516   3  0.655    0.510  0.215      1.7835        0.8885        0.4095      0.4195   1
529    1  0.570    0.450  0.160      0.9715        0.3965        0.2550      0.2600   1
1244   2  0.385    0.280  0.085      0.2175        0.0970        0.0380      0.0670   2
1880   2  0.545    0.430  0.140      0.6870        0.2615        0.1405      0.2500   2
1311   2  0.545    0.405  0.135      0.5945        0.2700        0.1185      0.1850   2
1759   3  0.735    0.590  0.215      1.7470        0.7275        0.4030      0.5570   1
```

My membership class is Age and I want to build a lasso model with it, which I have done. The problem is that the predict() function returns this error and I have no idea what to do about it: "The number of variables in newx must be 8" .

The code I have used is below:

```
myabalone<-read.table(file.choose(), header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)

myabalone$Sex<-as.numeric(myabalone$Sex)
myabalone$Age<-as.numeric(myabalone$Age)

set.seed(69)
mysampleabalone<-myabalone[sample(nrow(myabalone)),]
train<-mysampleabalone[1:floor(nrow(mysampleabalone)*0.7),]
test<-mysampleabalone[(floor(nrow(mysampleabalone)*0.7)+1):nrow(mysampleabalone),]

set.seed(300)
x<-model.matrix(Age~., train)[,-1]
y<-ifelse(train$Age=="1", "1", "0")
cv.lasso<-cv.glmnet(x,y, alpha=1, family="binomial")

model2<-glmnet(x,y, family="binomial", alpha=1, lambda=cv.lasso$lambda.1se)

set.seed(123)
predicted<-predict(model2, test, type = "response")
```

This is where the "The number of variables in newx must be 8" error occurs.

Why should there be 8 variables and not 9, if the training data I used to build the model also has 9 variables? I have seen in other posts suggested that I should try to pass the test set as.data.frame(), because there might be some issues with the column names, but I tried and nothing. Plus, when I use the head() function on it, it returns exactly the same column names as the training set used for the building the model.

Anybody has any ideas how do I fix this?

Comment: You appear to have an unnamed column on the right hand side of your output from `head()`.  Your `model.matrix` statement defines your predictors to be "all columns other than the one containing the dependent".  You have eight named columns, one unnamed column.  That makes nine.  That might have something to do with it.  Values in your `Sex` column look odd and `myabalone$Sex<-as.numeric(myabalone$Sex)` is probably wrong.

Comment: `x<-model.matrix(Age~., train)[,-1]` looks to me like `train` has 9 columns, but due to your `-1` `x` has 8 columns. Did you check `dim(x)`? I'd suggest doing the exact same processing on your `test` set as your `train` set, `test_x <- model.matrix(Age~., test)[,-1]`.

Comment: (@Limey I think that first "column" is probably row names, the indentation is poor making it look like it has a column name)

Comment: @GregorThomas.  Yes, I considered that.  But my other comments remain valid even if that is the case.  (For example, `Sex` having values `1`, `2` and `3`, so conversion to numeric is likely to be erroneous...).  Your observation about the use of `[,-1]` is also very relevant, I suspect!

Comment: I assume this is the [UCI abalone data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/abalone) with 3 sex categories: male, female, infant. Though agreed that numeric is a poor choice for a 3-level factor.